# Http post request to php with dart

Tags: php, api, post, dart

I tried to post data to php backend using dart. Somehow using ajax, I can get the response but with dart, it shows 
`<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'email' of non-object in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPBackend\api\login\login_account.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'password' of non-object in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPBackend\api\login\login_account.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />`

These are my php codes for login.

```
// login_account.php
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$login = new Login($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$login->email = $data->email;
$login->password = $data->password;

$login->loginAccount();

$login_arr = array(
  "email" => $login->email,
  "password" => $login->password
);

print_r(json_encode($login_arr));
?>
```

```
// login.php
function loginAccount(){

    // query to read single record
    $query = "SELECT
    email, password
    FROM
    " . $this->table_name . " WHERE
    email = :email AND password = :password";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

    // sanitize
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
    $this->password=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));

    // bind id of food to be updated
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $this->email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $this->password);
    die($this->email);
    die($this->password);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // set values to object properties
    $this->email = $row['email'];
    $this->password = $row['password'];
  }
}
```

And this is how I tried to get the response using dart. `emailValue` and `passwordValue` getting from textfields.

```
    var loginObj = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    loginObj['email'] = emailValue;
    loginObj['password'] = passwordValue;

    final response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.1.90/phpbackend/api/login/login_account.php"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
        body: loginObj);
    print(response.body); // check the status code for the result
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to send a Map as your body without converting it into e.g. JSON?

Comment: Can you please tell us which line of code `line 23` refers to?

Comment: Could you pls show me how to convert into JSON using dart? @julemand101

Comment: `line 23` and `line 24` are the following codes. `$login->email = $data->email;
$login->password = $data->password;`

Comment: @Lucas https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.1/dart-convert/json-constant.html

Comment: Wow. I just need to convert them into JSON. Pls put down your answer so that I can accept. @julemand101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in the Dart code that your are trying to send the Map object directly instead of first converting it into e.g. JSON.

To convert to JSON you can use the dart:convert package and the following method:

```
var encodedLoginObj = json.encode(loginObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional Information

There is a dart package that provides some helper classes for http requests.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Install it with:

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.5.1
```

It is also part of the EZ-Flutter Collection :

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter
Docs : https://ez-flutter.de/docs

```
dependencies:
  ez_flutter: ^0.2.5
```

Usage

```dart
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Some": "Header"
};
Map<String, String> queryParameters = {
  "Some": "Parameter"
};

String url = "";
Map payload = "{}";

    Map<String, dynamic> reaponseBody;
    try {
        responseBody = await HttpUtils.postForJson(url, json. encode(payload) ,
        queryParameters: queryParameters, headers: headers);
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle exception, for example if response status code != 200-299
    }
    // do something with the response body
```

Additional information :

These are all methods from the HttpUtils class.

```dart
Future<Map<Response> getForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getForJson(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> getForString(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<Response> postForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> postForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response> putForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> putForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> putForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response deleteForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deleteForJson(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> deleteForString(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Map<String, dynamic> getQueryParameterFromUrl(String url);
String addQueryParameterToUrl(String url, Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters);
```